# embedding of two spaces

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Can it be said that $(H_0^1(\Omega)\bigcap L^{\infty}(\Omega), ||..||_{1,2})$ can be continuously embedded in $(C(\Omega),||..||_{\infty})$, where $\Omega$ is a bounded subset of $\textbf{R}^n$, $n \geq 1$?.

Comment: You need an estimate of the form $\|u\|_\infty \le C \|u\|_{1,2}$. This is simple when $n=1$, but generally false in higher dimensions

Comment: Thanks Umberto!. But don't you think that your claim holds when you consider $H_0^1(\Omega)$ and not $H_0^1(\Omega)\bigcap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$?. I am asking this because the set $H_0^1(\Omega)\bigcap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ not only consists of functions whose weak derivative is in $L^2(\Omega)$ but also which are bounded a.e. It will be great if you can clear this doubt.

Comment: The problem is that you are using the $\|\cdot\|_{1,2}$ norm on $H_0^1(\Omega) \cap L^\infty(\Omega)$. You can have a sequence $\{v_k\}$ with the property that $\|v_k\|_{1,2} = 1$ for all $k$ but $\|v_k\|_\infty \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the following result?

> If $\Omega$ is bounded, $f \in H^1_0(\Omega)$, $\Phi : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is bounded and Lipschitz, and $\Phi(0) = 0$, then $\Phi \circ f \in H^1_0(\Omega)$.

For instance, if $\alpha > 0$ is sufficiently small and $f(x) = |x|^{-\alpha} - 1$, then $f \in H^1_0(B(0,1))$ (at least when $n \ge 3$ -- you need a somewhat different example when $n=2$). In light of the result above, $\sin(f) \in H^1_0(B(0,1))$, but $\sin(f)$ is not continuous at the origin.

Comment: Thanks Umberto for the insightful answer. One last question (which probably could be naive. Pardon me for my naivity if it is so). Is the space $H_0^1(\Omega)\bigcap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ w.r.t. $||..||_{1,2}$ complete?.

Comment: No. You could (for example) take truncations of the function $f$ above. They are all bounded and converge to $f$ in the $H^1_0$ norm so they form a Cauchy sequence in $H^1_0 \cap L^\infty$. But the sequence doesn't converge in $H^1_0 \cap L^\infty$.

Comment: What about using the norm $\|u\|_\infty + \|Du\|_2$?

Comment: @Umbreto...But isn't it that the truncations of $f$ may not give a function in $H_0^1(\Omega)$?.

Comment: Since $\overline{C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)}=H_0^1(\Omega)$ hence $\overline{C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)}=H_0^1(\Omega)\bigcap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$. By this can't it be concluded that $H_0^1(\Omega)\bigcap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ is closed?.

Comment: The function $T_n(x)$ given by $n$ if $x > n$, $x$ if $|x| \le n$, and $-n$ if $x < -n$ is Lipschitz, so if $f \in H^1(\Omega)$ then so is $T_n(f)$. $T_n(f)$ is the truncation of $f$ at level $n$. Since values of $f$ near zero are unaffected by the truncation, $f \in H^1_0 \implies T_n(f) \in H^1_0$.

Comment: The claim $\overline{C_0^\infty(\Omega)} = H^1_0(\Omega) \cap L^\infty(\Omega)$ is incorrect.

Comment: Great to learn!...Just for my knowledge why can't I say that since $C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)\subset H_0^1(\Omega)\bigcap L^{\infty}(\Omega)\subset H_0^1{\Omega}$ and since $C_0^{\infty}$ is dense in $H_0^1(\Omega)$ so $C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$ is dense in $H_0^1(\Omega)\bigcap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$?.

Comment: The proper conclusion to your last comment is that $H_0^1 \cap L^\infty$ is dense in $H_0^1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Umberto!. If you don't mind can I have your email id so that I can mail you the problem I am working on?.

Comment: @Alexander click anywhere on my name to get to my profile. The email is there.